# upload não envia arquivos depois de um determinado tamanho

Tags: php

Colegas.

tenho uma parte do sistema que envia arquivos pdf para o servidor:

```
list($arquivo, $extensao) = explode(".",$arquivoNome);
    $codificar = md5(date('h:i').$arquivo).".".$extensao;
    $dirArquivo = "uploads/pdf/";
    $upArquivo = $dirArquivo . basename($codificar);

    if(move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $upArquivo)){
      ......
}
```

O problema é que se o arquivo for leve, funciona, mas se o arquivo tiver acima de 1MB não envia.

Comment: Isso mesmo, seu servidor deve ter uma restrição ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os arquivos enviados forem maiores que valor definido pelo servidor, altera o `upload_max_filesize` no php.ini com um valor adequado e para terminar o processo reinicie o apache.

```
upload_max_filesize=5M
```

- `upload_max_filesize` é tamanho dos uploads enviados para o servidor.
- `max_file_uploads` é o número maximo de arquivos enviados na requisição.

Comment: o problema o servidor é externo

Comment: @Jose.Marcos, veja no php o valor de `upload_max_filesize`